# Ошибка при инициализации vue.js

Tags: vue.js

```
$ npm init vue@3
npx: установлен 1 в 2.442s
C:\Users\Roderen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\7096\node_modules\create-vue\outfile.cjs:5667
  const isFeatureFlagsUsed = typeof (argv.default ?? argv.ts ?? argv.jsx ?? argv.router ?? argv.pinia ?? argv.tests ?? argv.vitest ??
argv.cypress ?? argv.eslint) === "boolean";
                                                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Версии npm и node:

```
node v12.0.0
npm v6.9.0
```

Не знаю уже что и делать.

Comment: Обновите ноду, актуальная версия на данный момент 18.4

Comment: @Jour Дело в том, что мне ещё нужно установить и на ноут (как раз с ним и проблемы), а он 10ю винду не берёт и приходится на 7ке сидеть с ним. Максимум 13 версия ноды на 7ке

Comment: установите линукс на этот ноут, проблем подобных у вас не возникнет)

Comment: @Jour Тю! Оказывается можно было вручную поставить ноду последнюю на вин 7

Comment: @Jour О лине уже думаю давно, но у них вроде были проблемы с драйверами на nvidia, которые недавно решились

Comment: более 2х лет на линукс минт, из замеченных проблем, видеокодеки для браузера опера криво становятся, но решается первой ссылкой гугла)